# Why is getValue() always returning false?

Tags: checkbox, gwt

I filled a list with a CheckBox. This Checkbox is screnning on the page. Then i will find out, if the Checkbox is checked or not. But this is Always returning false, even when the Checkbox is pressed. But why?

```
ArrayList<TutorialAnswerCheckbox> cbList = new ArrayList<>();
cbList.add(new TutorialAnswerCheckbox(false, "Zuweisungsoperatoren"));
```

Here the Checkbox is created.

```
public TutorialAnswerCheckbox(boolean isCorrectAnswer, String text)
{
    this.isCorrectAnswer = isCorrectAnswer;
    setText(text);
    getElement().getStyle().setColor("black");
    getElement().getStyle().setProperty("float", "left");
}
```

Here im adding the box to my HTMLPanel to a answer div.

```
html.add(cbList.get(0), "answer9");
```

This works. Then when the user hits a button i will check if the checkbox is pressed or not.

```
@UiHandler("abgabe")
void done(ClickEvent e) 
{
    Window.alert(cbList.get(0).isAnswerCorrectly.toString());
    
}

public boolean isAnswerCorrectly()
{
    return this.getValue();
}
```

But the window alert is Always false
This Returns also false even when it is checked.

```
Window.alert(cbList.get(0).isAnswerCorrectly.toString());
```

Comment: Where is TutorialAnswerCheckbox defined?  It looks like this is part of your own code, but isn't listed in the question?

Comment: I only create the Checkbox and store them in a list. But every Checkbox in this list is returning false by getValue() even it is checked

Comment: Please add more code about the TutorialAnswerCheckbox  to be able to better understand what is going on

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the fireEvents `checkbox.setValue(value, fireEvents);`